# Is there an OS X app like jsfiddle?

Tags: macos, javascript

I am wondering if there is an app that works like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to work offline for prototyping on the move?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just looking for a jsFiddle clone as well and came across [Diddle](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?135851-Simple-ExtJS-4-jsfiddle-clone) which is a simple clone of the jsFiddle UI but lacking the ability to include different libraries. It was only written as an experiment but maybe it is good enough for your prototyping needs.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a very simple plugin for Vim called [vimfiddler](https://github.com/codeape2/vimfiddler). If you are a Vim user and your Vim is compiled with Python support, you should be able to use it on a Mac.

Video: http://vimeo.com/32148952

Answer (score 0):

You can of course just set up an HTML file with a script block, and load and refresh that. In combination with the inspector in Webkit or Firebug for Firefox, you are away!

Answer (score 0):

Triplety is the only app I'm aware of. Pretty useful for local testing and development.

https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/triplety-playground-for-web/id654989327?mt=12

Features (excerpt from the App description):

- Built-in Preview with live reload
- Local HTTP server with live reload for external browsers (Live reload for modern browsers including iOS4.2+)
- Auto-Completion HTML, CSS and Javascript
- Support LESS, SCSS+Compass and CoffeeScript
- Importing
- CSS libraries
- Javascript libraries
- Resource files (e.g. PNG images)
- Your own Triplety's project
- Live CSSLint, JSHint
- Beautify HTML, CSS, and Javascript
- Exporting Triplety’s project
- Full retina support